# Remove column if it is equal to another column and has certain name part

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this data frame

```
df <- data.frame(a.paid = c("A", "A", "B"), a.written = c("A", "A", "B"),
                 b.paid = c(1, 3, 4), b.written = c(1, 3, 4),
                 c.paid = c(1, 3, 5), c.written = c(2, 3, 5),
                 t = c(1, 1, 1))
```

and I wish to reduce the number of columns by some sort of test. E.g. if the entire column of a.paid is equal to a.written, then remove a.written. But over the entire data frame, such that it includes all cases where the names have paid and written in common.

With dplyr preferebly.

Frankly, I do not know how to solve this problem but to do it "by hand". ChatGPT was in this case not very helpful either, nor Google - but perhaps my wording and searching skills weren't precise enough.

The expected outcome should be this:

```
 a.paid b.paid c.paid c.written t
1      A      1      1         2 1
2      A      3      3         3 1
3      B      4      5         5 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure we are only comparing pairs of columns, we can make use of `across`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

target_cols <- 
  df %>% mutate(
    # this make sure we are comparing pairs
    across(ends_with("paid"), ~if (sub("paid", "written", cur_column()) %in% colnames(df)) .x == get(sub("paid", "written", cur_column())) else T), 
    # if paid are all TURE, set written to FALSE
    across(ends_with("written"), ~ifelse(sub("written", "paid", cur_column()) %in% colnames(df), 
                                         ifelse(all(get(sub("written", "paid", cur_column()))), F, T), 
                                         T)), 
    # catch anything that's not in pairs
    across(where(~!is.logical(.x)), ~ifelse(!is.null(.x), T, F))) %>% 
  select(where(~any(.x))) %>% 
  colnames()

# use indexing to get the correct columns
df[,target_cols]
#>   a.paid b.paid c.paid c.written t
#> 1      A      1      1         2 1
#> 2      A      3      3         3 1
#> 3      B      4      5         5 1
```

Comment: Oh, this is a really good solution. But it stops working if there is a d.paid column but not a d.written column!

Comment: @CodingCat Fixed :) Tested with `d.paid` without `d.written` and `d.written` without `d.paid`.

Comment: Wow, that solved it super neatly! I changed `ends_with` to `contains` to make it a little more general. Thank you SO much for this code.  

Also in the first `colnames(df)` I changed it to `colnames(.)` (my df name was very long...) but how come the code does not work if I do the same in the last time `colnames(df)` is mentioned? 
I don't really understand all what the code does. What does .x signify and do? :)

Comment: @CodingCat I'm not sure if it's a good practice to use `.` within `across`. If your dataframe name is too long, you can use `df_colnames <- colnames(df)` and use `df_colnames` to replace `colnames(df)` in the code. When you create a function using `tidyverse` syntax (`~`), `.x` is the first parameter of the function. Hopes it clears you confusion :)

Answer (score 3):

```r
df <- data.frame(a.paid = c("A", "A", "B"), a.written = c("A", "A", "B"),
                 b.paid = c(1, 3, 4), b.written = c(1, 3, 4),
                 c.paid = c(1, 3, 5), c.written = c(2, 3, 5),
                 t = c(1, 1, 1))

library(tidyverse)
slct <- map(df, ~.x) %>% duplicated()
```

or **base**

```r
slct <- lapply(df, function(x) x) |> duplicated()

df[!slct]
#>   a.paid b.paid c.paid c.written t
#> 1      A      1      1         2 1
#> 2      A      3      3         3 1
#> 3      B      4      5         5 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! That map seems smart. I re-did it a bit because I got an error with `df[!slct]`. I made a tiny mistake by putting paid before written in the example. My own data was opposite. So instead I rearranged the order to be paid before written in my data and did `df %>% select_if(!slct)`. If I did not reorder, it selected the writtens instead of paid.
Maybe you could help with how to do it with `select_if(!slct)` without reordering if it was a data frame with many more columns, please :)

Comment: Note if there's any "un-related" column that have the same values as your paired-columns, that will also be removed. Try setting `t = c(1, 3, 5)` (or worse `c.paid = c(1, 3, 4)`).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use `duplicated`

```
> df[!duplicated(as.list(df))]
  a.paid b.paid c.paid c.written t
1      A      1      1         2 1
2      A      3      3         3 1
3      B      4      5         5 1
```